# What path does one specify for JAVA_HOME on a Mac OS environment?

Tags: macos, plugins, java, java-home

When an application or plug-in install states that the JAVA_HOME variable point you my JDK, what export statement do I need to put in my .bash_profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browse to: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/

Then, pick an alias to a version or 'CurrentJDK'.

export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home

then add $JAVA_HOME to your PATH.

Comment: Found it ... i should add the reminder that it is under the Eclipse -> Preferences not in the Build Path where I tried looking before.

Answer (score 9):

The proper way to set JAVA_HOME is to invoke the `java_home(1)` tool (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html). This can be done as follows to use defaults:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Valko Sipuli.

I'm using Mac OS Yosemite and

> JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

did the trick for running ant.